# MongoDB Query Using Dynamic Array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I'm having a problem using a dynamic array to filter the data I want to retrieve from my MongoDB.

I have an array which is stored in `$this->x` and when I `print_r($this->x)` the result is the same as before:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 54
    [3] => 55
)
```

but the query won't return any values. Query -> `$c = $col->find(array('Aliens.Id' => array('$in' => $this->x)));`

The strange thing is that when I do the query like this -> `$c = $col->find(array('Aliens.Id' => array('$in' => array(1,2,54,55)));` it returns values!!

If I `print_r(array(1,2,54,55))` the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 54
    [3] => 55
)
```

Note: `$this->x` is also an array.

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950525/mongodb-php-using-in-with-array

Comment: Thansk a lot @prakashtank. It was built as an array of strings

Comment: glad it worked !!!